# How to create shapefile without trailing zeros using R

Tags: r, dataframe, shapefile

I am creating a shapefile but the data columns all have trailing zeros eg: 1.000000000000000

How do I limit the trailing zeros to 2 digits eg: 1.00 ?

Sample code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(sp)

coords <- cbind(c(631145, 631757, 631928, 631664, 631579, 631281), c(6967640, 6967566, 6968027, 6967985, 6968141, 6968009))
poly <- Polygons(list(Polygon(coords)),"coords")
poly.sp <- SpatialPolygons(list(poly))

df<- data.frame(id = getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(poly.sp))
row.names(df) <- getSpPPolygonsIDSlots(poly.sp)

spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(poly.sp, data=df)
spdf@data$VALUE <- 1
writeOGR(spdf, "shapes", "testShape", driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite=TRUE)
```

When I open the .dbf file in a text editor (Notepad++) the `1` is displayed with trailing zeros.

Comment: Why is that a problem?

Comment: I'm amazed you can open DBF files in Notepad++ though. They're all binary. Or does notepad++ have a plugin for them?

Comment: Actually, do you want integers? Or do you want to store floating point numbers at some reduced precision? Or just have Notepad++ display them with fewer decimals? Not at all clear.

Comment: @Roland: The shapefiles are used in a system where apparently the decimal places are an issue. By manually removing them in a GIS package the problem is resolved.

Comment: @Spacedman: Notepad++ doesn't show it nice/neatly but the information is in there somewhere. I used notepad just to make sure that the program (SAGA GIS, Excel etc) doesn't apply its own formatting.

At this stage the result values are all integers but the data-type that we use in our accompanying system is double.

Comment: The system appears to be, lets say, of suboptimal quality if it needs input with a specific number of decimal digits.

Comment: I agree, the catch is that I don't even know what the system is called because the end-user of the shapefile is our client's client's client. What we know is that our shapefiles cannot be read by their system. We are trying to figure out what the cause is and like I mentioned, by manually removing the excess zeros the problem is resolved so this is our troubleshooting starting point.

Comment: "Removing the excess zeroes" isn't a meaningful expression. The DBF file format [http://www.dbf2002.com/dbf-file-format.html] stores numeric values with a "Length of field" and a "number of decimals". I suspect your client's client's client is being fussy about these field parameters. What do they want? Width=10, decimals=2?

Answer (score 1):

Your shapefile DBF is storing it as a Real value, and you want Integers.

```
> ogrInfo("./shapes","testShape")
Source: "./shapes", layer: "testShape"
Driver: ESRI Shapefile; number of rows: 1 
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
Extent: (631145 6967566) - (631928 6968141)
LDID: 87 
Number of fields: 2 
   name type length typeName
1    id    4     80   String
2 VALUE    2     24     Real
```

R creates its numeric columns by default as floating point numbers. The column class is "numeric":

```
> class(spdf$VALUE)
[1] "numeric"
```

Change this to "integer"L

```
> class(spdf$VALUE)="integer"
> class(spdf$VALUE)
[1] "integer"
```

And rewrite your shapefile:

```
> writeOGR(spdf, "shapes", "testShape", driver="ESRI Shapefile", overwrite=TRUE)
```

And now

```
> ogrInfo("./shapes","testShape")
Source: "./shapes", layer: "testShape"
Driver: ESRI Shapefile; number of rows: 1 
Feature type: wkbPolygon with 2 dimensions
Extent: (631145 6967566) - (631928 6968141)
LDID: 87 
Number of fields: 2 
   name type length typeName
1    id    4     80   String
2 VALUE    0     10  Integer
```

Integer field in the shapefile DBF. Job done.

Comment: @beetroot yes, have commented for clarity.

Comment: @Spacedman: Ideally I'd want the result to be 1.00. What would the class be for decimal/double?